# Laravel Loop Through Multidimesional Array

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to loop through a multidimensional array in my view.

the array (I am passing $mailchimp from my controller to my view) is:

```
    array:19 [▼
      "id" => "f3200e9cc5a900bb7c075103b871232f0"
      "email_address" => "john.doe@discworld.com"
      "unique_email_id" => "xalasd"
      "email_type" => "html"
      "status" => "subscribed"
      "merge_fields" => array:2 [▼
        "FNAME" => "John"
        "LNAME" => "Doe"
      ]
      "stats" => array:2 [▶]
      "ip_signup" => ""
      "timestamp_signup" => ""
      "ip_opt" => "93.212.91.32"
      "timestamp_opt" => "2016-10-27T13:53:02+00:00"
      "member_rating" => 2
      "last_changed" => "2016-10-27T13:53:02+00:00"
      "language" => ""
      "vip" => false
      "email_client" => ""
      "location" => array:6 [▶]
      "list_id" => "76980934492"
      "_links" => array:8 [▶]
    ]
```

With this Code in my view:

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $user)
    @foreach($user as $key => $value)
      <ul>
        <li>{{$value}}</li>
       </ul>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

An exception is thrown: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can somebody tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: The first code snippet you posted is of a single array for a single user, not a multi-dimensional array of multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

you are expecting for the value of each of the first array to also be an array. That is not the case, only some values from the first array is an array, so you must put a condition. You can use the `is_array` helper to see if the value from the first array is an actual array, if so, loop thru each one of those.

```
foreach($a as $b){
    if(is_array($b)){
        foreach($b as $c){
            echo($c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. It tried you solution with this result: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Carlos the main issue you're encountering is because you're trying to echo an array [find his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307294/laravel-loop-through-multidimesional-array/40307989#40307989).

Regarding your second issue `Thanks Carlos. It tried you solution with this result: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` do you have any other code on that page, perhaps {{ Form::text('something', $array) }}

Comment: I deleted all other code. and tried with Carlos suggestion. The Exception still remains. any idea?